# Restler 3 nested resources?

Tags: php, rest, restler

In restler, is is possible to use nested resources?  For example, with restler I would do the normal `/api/account/123` call to get that specific account.  Now I  want to get the clients that belong to that account.  So I'd want to also call `/api/account/123/client/456` for example to get the specific client for the specific account.

Comment: Here is the thread that discusses the possibilities https://github.com/Luracast/Restler/issues/294

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use manual routing to define such routes. See the following example

```
use Luracast\Restler\RestException;

class Accounts
{

    /**
     * Get specific client for the given account
     *
     * @param int $id account id
     * @param int $client_id
     *
     * @throws RestException 404
     *
     * @return Client
     *
     * @url GET accounts/{id}/clients/{client_id}
     */
    public function getClient($id, $client_id)
    {
        $r = Client::where('account_id', '=', $id)->where('id', '=', $client_id)->firstOrFail();
        if (empty($r))
            throw RestException(404, 'Client is not found associated with the account');
        return $r;
    }

    /**
     * Get all clients associated with the given account
     *
     * @param int $id account id
     *
     * @return array {@type Client}
     *
     * @url GET accounts/{id}/clients
     */
    public function getClients($id)
    {
        return Client::where('account_id', '=', $id)->all();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you improve upon the explorer so that it shows the return type as well as the exceptions thrown?

Comment: Did you try the Explorer class in RC6?

Comment: RC6?  The github page says RC5

Comment: PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in .../vendor/Luracast/Restler/AutoLoader.php on line 266  and also  PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class Closure could not be converted to string in .../vendor/Luracast/Restler/AutoLoader.php on line 266    This is with PHP 5.4.24

Comment: What's the right way to call another API class?  While I can directly access the Client model like you show above, I probably have a class in my Clients API for doing that already, with other logic wrapped around it. So from the Accounts API I want to call the Clients API

Comment: Here is some pseudo code to improve on https://github.com/Luracast/Restler/issues/294#issuecomment-43644090